# Can we have a sticky area for meta questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, canonical-questions

This would be for questions/answers that fall into the category of generally useful references.
canon

[Let's compile a list of canonical Q&As](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2708/4671)
is the current example that comes to mind, but I'm sure there are others. We really should be more systematically creating a list of canonical questions/answers and referring people to it. I had to spend some time searching for it just now. If it was permanently globally visible in meta, that would be helpful.

ADDENDUM: Should this be put on [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

I would say no. We have tags to categorize this. I don't see a need to use something else. You can add favorite tags if you are interested.